# При отправке формы через requests.post не делает переадресацию на дргую старницу

Tags: python, парсер, requests, post

Пишу парсер для [сайта](https://portalsat.plataforma.sat.gob.mx/RecuperacionDeCertificados/faces/index.xhtml) . Там есть капча которую вроде как возможно успешно решаю, потом пробую отправлять с помощю requests.post запрос с хедером куками ну формой status.code 200, якобы все отправил хорошо, но нету ответа.

Вот мой код

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib3.util import create_urllib3_context
from urllib3 import PoolManager
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests import Session
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import tempfile
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha


class AddedCipherAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
  def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
    ctx = create_urllib3_context(ciphers=":HIGH:!DH:!aNULL")
    self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
      num_pools=connections,
      maxsize=maxsize,
      block=block,
      ssl_context=ctx
    )


def main():
    ua = UserAgent()
    base_url = 'https://portalsat.plataforma.sat.gob.mx'
    url = 'https://portalsat.plataforma.sat.gob.mx/RecuperacionDeCertificados'
    session = Session()
    session.mount(base_url, AddedCipherAdapter())
    response = session.get(url)
    cookies = response.cookies
    print(cookies)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(response.text, 'lxml')
        img = soup.find_all('img')
        hide_input = soup.find('input', {'type':'hidden' , 'name': 'javax.faces.ViewState'})
        img = [i.get('src') for i in img if i.get('height') == '50']
        response = session.get(f'{base_url}{img[0]}')
        temp_file_path = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.jpg')
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
        image = image.convert('RGB')
        image.save('TEST.jpg', 'JPEG')
        image.save(temp_file_path, 'JPEG')
        solver = TwoCaptcha('b881cd06fb0b03e34cd95e4bb7a6f55f')
        result = solver.normal(temp_file_path, caseSensitive=1)
        form_post = '/RecuperacionDeCertificados/faces/index.xhtml'
        print(result)
        data = {
            'form': 'form',
            'form: verTexto': result.get('code'),
            'form: j_idt21': 'Aceptar',
            'javax.faces.ViewState': hide_input.get('value'),
        }
        print(result.get('code'))
        headers = {
            'user-agent': ua.random,
            "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,uk-UA;q=0.8,uk;q=0.7,pl;q=0.6",
            "cache-control": "max-age=0",
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "sec-ch-ua": "Not.A/Brand;v=8, Chromium;v=114, Google Chrome;v=114",
            "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
            "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
            "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
            "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
            "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
            "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
            "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
        }
        response = session.post(f'{base_url}{form_post}', data=data, headers=headers,cookies=cookies)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print('Форма успішно відправлена!')
            print(response.history)
            if 'Recuperación por RFC:' in response:
                solver.report(result.get('captchaId'), True)
                print("Відбулося перенаправлення")
                # Отримання остаточного URL після перенаправлення
                final_url = response.url
                print("Остаточний URL:", final_url)
            if '¡Ocurrió un error durante su solicitud!' in response:
                print("Перенаправлення не відбулося")
                final_url = response.url
                print("Остаточний URL:", final_url)
                solver.report(result.get('captchaId'), False)
            else:
                print('fail')
        else:
            print('Помилка при відправці форми.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Как так "Нет ответа"? Может, всё же, что-то пишет, какой код?